# Show another tab than first one at starting android

Tags: android, tabs

Is it possible display one tab or another in android dynamically?

I am trying to make an app with 3 tabs but sometimes is possible that one or two tabs will not have content (not buttons or data in activities) so I want just show the activity which has data or one of both with it.

I want to keep the possibility that the user navigate to tabs without content but I want to show firstly the tab with it.

I am following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ to do the tabs. I mean, if you need my code to make any modification or add anything. For the moment I just want to have an example to show it and after that start adding my code, which already works in an older app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move to the tab by using

```
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(item_position);
  getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(item_position);
```

Comment: This works for changing the tab but when I try to use it after viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter); it does nothing. I tried: viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); for example

Comment: Ok, it seems to work because it loads the view that I want, but the tab is not changed. It always shows the first one as selected even showing the second or third info. How can I change the tab selection?

Comment: I edit your answer to add info to my second question in your comments.